# Is there a way to modify OpenNebula log timing format?

Tags: logging, time, opennebula

I want to modify the granularity of the time in OpenNebula log, in order to have a format like hour:mins:sec milliseconds. I modified common_scripts.sh in which there are some functions for logging purpose but the results weren't satisfying. Any clues about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the time format, you have to change the ctime_r functions in [Log.cc](https://github.com/OpenNebula/one/blob/master/src/log/Log.cc#L99) and use [strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead.